# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, extjs, extjs4

- I am new to js,

  - I am getting an  error at the line popup.location.href =
    "/desktop/main"; as Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
    'location' of undefined,
  - how to fix the problem
  - providing my code below

    ```
            success: function () {
                //   me.showNewWindowSuccess(menu, newWindowId);
                me.registerMenuClick(menu, newWindowId);
                popup.location.href = "";
            },
            scope: me
        });
    },
    ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing the url to the function `openNewWindow`

the `if(url)` returns false in the function, so it never returns anything.

thats the reason for `popup` to be `undefined`

Comment: What are you trying to do? Open a blank popup window initially and then in the ajax success redirect to `/desktop/main` ?